# Combining two lists into one in Scala

Tags: scala

How to combine the following two lists into one such that:

```
L1 = List((a,1), (b,2), (c,3), (d,4))
L2 = List((a,b), (b,c), (a,d))
```

and combined list will be:

```
L3 = List((1,2), (2,3), (1,‌​4))
```

Comment: Whaaaaaaaat........ ? Whaaaaat.... ? What is the rule that maps list 1 and list 2 with the output ?

Comment: this is what OP means.  L1 = List((a,1),(b,2), (c,3), d,4)) and L2 = List((a,b), (b,c), (a,d)) => L3 = List((1,2),(2,3),(1,3)).

Comment: @hsuk I answered your question around 10 hors ago. I think it is what you needed.

Answer (score 2):

Ok. So first you will need to convert first list to map.

```
val l1 = List((1,1),(4,4),(5,4),(8,4),(9,5))
val l2 = List((1,4),(1,9),(5,9),(8,9))

val mapL1 = l1.toMap

val requiredList = l2.map({ case (i, j) => (mapL1(i), mapL1(j)) })
```

Comment: you may remove `{}` in the last line.

Comment: Good job at understanding the rule which transforms the second list (given very vague problem statement) :)